# How to handle the response for Feedly Authentication?

Tags: ios, api, authentication, query-string, feedly

[Feedly API Documentation](http://developer.feedly.com/v3/auth/#authenticating-a-user-and-obtaining-a-code)

I'm trying to take advantage of Feedly APIs in my testing iOS app, but unfortunately it seems too great a confusion to me, a newbie to coding in general.

I encountered a problem at the very beginning.
The first step required is the Authentication, as shown in the link above. So **I write the code below:**

```
NSDictionary *queryParams = @{@"response_type" : @"code",
                              @"client_id" : clientID, //some NSString
                              @"redirect_uri" : redirectURL, //@"https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost/"
                              @"scope" : @"https://cloud.feedly.com/subscriptions"
                              };

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://developer.feedly.com/"]];


[httpClient getPath:@"/v3/auth"
         parameters:queryParams
            success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                NSLog(@"response: %@", responseObject);


            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"HTTP Requset Operation Error! %@", error);
            }];
```

It appeared that I succeeded in getting the response when I ran the code, since the response was logged. However, the output was like this:

```
<3c21444f 43545950 45206874 6d6c3e0a 3c68746d 6c206c61 6e673d22 656e223e 0a3c6865 61643e0a 20203c6d 65746120 68747470 2d657175 69763d22 436f6e74 656e742d 54797065 2220636f 6e74656e 743d2274 6578742f 68746d6c 3b206368 61727365 743d5554 462d3822 202f3e0a 20203c6d 65746120 68747470 2d657175 69763d22 436f6e74 656e742d 4c616e67 75616765 2220636f 6e74656e 743d2265 6e2d7573 22202f3e 0a20203c 6d657461 20687474 702d657 ......(the list goes on and on)>
```

I'm really clueless about what type this is and how I can use it. Is it the response mentioned in the documentation?

Here is the part related to handling the response:

> Handling the response
>
> The response will be sent to the redirect_uri specified in the request. If the user approves the access request, then the response contains an code and the state parameter (if included in the request). If the user does not approve the request the response contains an error message. All responses are returned to the web server on the query string, as shown below:
>
> An error response:
>
> https://your.redirect.uri/feedlyCallback?error=access_denied&state=state.passed.in
>
> A code response
>
> https://your.redirect.uri/feedlyCallback?code=AQAA7rJ7InAiOjEsImEiOiJmZWVk…&state=state.passed.in

What does it mean "All responses are returned to the web server on the query string" and how can I access the returned parameters?(This seems to be the part where I'm stumped)

**Thanks for anyone who can lead me out of this mess and give me faith to continue coding.**

**Plus I'm really fuzzy about how to cope with these web service APIs and the whole url-query/response thing. I'd be vastly grateful if someone can name a book or some article from which I can learn something regarding the way this mechanism works.**

Answer (score 0):

**The response will be sent to the redirect_uri specified in the request.**

Check the response url:

https://**your.redirect.uri**/feedlyCallback?**error**=access_denied&**state**=state.passed.in

Notice the feedlyCallback? part and query strings **error** and **state**

I don't know what language you are using, but for PHP: you should create **feedlyCallback.php** and set php server to feed files without .php extension,

in php files, you can acces query strings with **$_GET['error']** and **$_GET['state']**

Just google for things you have problems with. No idea what query stings mean? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: I'm sorry but I use objective-C. Just added the ios tag. Do you know how to query the error and state, or code and state, parameters in objective-C? That seems to be the exact part where I'm stumped now. I didn't know the specific term to google for but I do now, thanks.